# OpenCV "waitkey" Not Working in Jupyther Notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter, ocr, python-tesseract

`cv2.waitkey(0)` shows no output and the kernel remains at a star (*).

I am working on Optical Character Recognition, OCR, using different Python libraries on Jupyter Notebook. When I wrote `cv2.waitkey(0)`, no output was shown and if some output was shown the star(*) remained.

Comment: hey, could you please clarify what do you mean? i am a bit confused about what is the output you expected and what is the output you recived

Comment: [mre] required.

Comment: It should be `cv2.waitKey(0)` with capital 'K' not `cv2.waitkey(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The strange thing is to use `cv2.imshow` in a notebook. Or a `cv2.waitKey`.
The point of a notebook is to be a bit like, well, a notebook, a document. With code and results.

`cv2.waitKey` is to wait for a key typed in the opencv window, and you don't have a cv2 window.

On a standalone machine, that is when jupyter server (it is a server, even for the very simple notebook, without jupyterlab or jupyterhub or anything like that. There is a miniwebserver, running a python kernel, and you interact with the server through a web browser client) is running on the same machine you are using to edit the notebook, as the same user, etc, then it may appear to work. Because attempt from the kernel to open a window to display an image will work: the kernel runs on the same machine, as the same user, so it has access to, and rights to, your screen.
But that window has nothing to do with the notebook.

And if the server is remote (google collab, or any jupyterhub/jupyterlab server, or even a simple noteboook accessed from another machine), then that can't work. The server won't be able to open a window. Or, even worse, it will, but will open the window on the server screen, in a server room miles from you :D
And then wait for someone to come in that server room to type a key :D

There are solutions for that.

For example `opencv_jupyter_ui` that replaces cv2 interactive functions by functions that can integrate with a notebook.

But for most usage, the solution is simply not to. Do you really need such an interactive way of using opencv in a notebook?

You can display an image very simply in a notebook.
For example, if a cell result is a PIL image, then, it is shown.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Just an image. Anything would do
img=(np.sin(np.linspace(0,1,500)[None,:]*(np.linspace(0,1,500)[:,None]+1)*10)*127+128).astype(np.uint8)

# If that is the last code of the cell, that is the result of the cell, 
# then the image is displayed as result
Image.fromarray(img)
```

So,  real question is, why do you need `cv2.waitKey`? Is it because opencv won't display the image before this is called? In that case, you don't need that in a notebook.
Or is it for another reason? Then you need to clarify what you are really trying to do.